# WPF clickable area around controls in grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, draggable

I have an issue with making a custom title bar for a form. It would contain a search textbox aswell as a few sliders, as seen on this image: 
[image: Example image]
Now, imagine that as the title bar - everything that is not a part of the controls themselves (the textbox which is surrounded by a border element, and the slider) needs to be mousedownable for dragging purposes.

I've tried this:

```
<Grid MouseDown="TitleGridMouseDown">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="135"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Slider Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 15 5 0" Width="100"  MouseDown="TitleGridMouseDown"/>
        <Slider Grid.Column="2" Margin="5 15 5 0"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Width="180" Height="20" Background="White">
            <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="20"/>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

However it's of no avail. There's a small part between the two sliders, like a few pixel area, which actually works (DragMove(); in the event itself). I don't have an awful lot of experience this type of things in WPF, but it feels to me like the area shrinks to the control. For instance, nothing changes if I place the border object into a button and try to bind the event to the button.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Have you tried using `PreviewMouseDown` on the `Grid` ?

Comment: Okay PreviewMouseDown actually starts working. However it seems to have the apparent side effect of disabling the functionality of mouse click and drag on underlying elements... ie I can't click in the textbox or drag the slider, because it just drags the window... hmm...

Comment: Right I've managed to solve this via a bit of a hack. I placed a rectangle in the exact same cell within the Grid, gave it transparent fill and then appended the mousedown event to it. I'm not sure if it has any negative effects and it certainly feels like a hack but... it works, strangely enough, flawlessly.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem here is that you want to capture the `MouseDown` event on the grid element. Since your grid has no Background set, its defaulted to null. The `MouseDown` event does not get raised. Think of it like it is going through the grid without actually hitting it. A `Background=Transparent` on your top grid should solve the problem.